# Dynamic record field by name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to make a regular copy of a table to a parent table and a child table. The parent table has few columns, e.g. company name, address and unique_identifier. The child table has more records because a company has more rows in the child table than in the parent table. The child's foreign key is joined to the parent's unique_id.
I perform this task with cursor, so I generate the unique_id inside the cursor. Each time I found a new company name in the ordered source, I step forward the unique_id.
There are many source and destination tables. I take their name from a configuration table, and I do a dynamic SQL with them. It works fine, no problem.
But the column_name of the company name column is not the same in all the source tables. It can be "comp_name", "MKN02" or anything else. How can I check it dynamically? I can put it in the config table but it will be a string and I need to compare the record.value to a variable. How will my string be variable?
My code is huge, I can't copy it here, so my sample is reduced dramatically. Please try to understand. I am happy to provide additional information if required.

```
Declare
    TYPE cur_typ Is Ref Cursor;
    cur cur_typ;
    my_rec owner1.table1%RowType;
    v_Prev varchar2(80) Default 'Empty'
    v_unique_id Number;
    v_SqlStmt Varchar2(1000);
Begin
    Open cur For 'Select * From '||owner1||'.'||table1||' Order By Comp_name';
    Loop
        Fetch cur Into my_rec;
        Exit When cur%notfound;
        If my_rec.Comp_Name <> v_Prev Then -- how to put "Comp_Name" column name to a variable?
            Select unique_id.nextval INTO v_unique_id FROM dual;
            v_SqlStmt := 'Insert into Parent_Table(Comp_name, Address, ID)
                         Values ('||my_rec.Comp_name||','||my_rec.Address||',:unique_id)';
            Execute Immediate v_SqlStmt using unique_id;
        End If; -- my_rec.Comp_name <> v_Prev
        v_SqlStmt := 'Insert into Child_table(unique_id, Invoice_No, Amount)
                      Values (:unique_id, :Invoice_No, :Amount)';
        Execute Immediate v_SqlStmt
            Using v_unique_id, my_rec.Invoice_No, my_rec.Amount;
        v_Prev := my_rec.Comp_name;
    End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Use that settings table to define column alias in dynamic query and access the same column statically

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Should I write a dynamic SQL to access one field of the record statically? How can I do that?